# Python/Django Writes u'' String To Postgresql (with UTF8 DB) and Munges Entry

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unicode

I'm sure that I've misconfigured something here, but I can't see what it is.

In Django, I've got a model field that says this:

```
short_url_slug = AutoSlugField(slugify=short_url_slugify, populate_from=id, blank=False, unique=True)
```

South creates a migration (seemingly) correctly:

```
'short_url_slug': ('autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField', [], {'unique_with': '()', 'max_length': '50', 'populate_from': 'None', 'blank': 'True'}),
```

My Postgresql DB is UTF8:

```
\l

(MyDBName)                      | (username) | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

And I have a real life unicode character:

```
u'\xa4'
```

But when I write this to the DB, and try to read it out, I get:

```
In [3]: this_instance.short_url_slug
Out[3]: u'o'
```

Thoughts? My suspicion is that Postgresql needs to have a different character encoding, but I'm not sure what it should be (if so) or how to do it.

**Edit With Additional Info**

```
SELECT version(), current_setting('standard_conforming_strings') AS scs;

PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2, compiled by i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00), 64-bit | on

(END)
```

Python Version:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
```

Django Version:

```
In [2]: django.VERSION
Out[2]: (1, 5, 1, 'final', 0)
```

psycopg2:

```
$ pip freeze | grep psycopg2
psycopg2==2.5
```

Raw log from postgresql:

```
LOG:  statement: UPDATE [...lots of stuff removed...] "short_url_slug" = 'o' [... rest of the stuff ...]
```

So, it looks like it's not even getting to Postgresql. But when I break at the line in the insertion, the variable definitely has the unicode value.

```
(Pdb) response.short_url_slug
u'\xd6'
```

(this is after assignment in Python, but before response.save())

**More Output:**

The way that I am detecting that the unicode is getting munged is that the database uniqueness constraint is getting violated. This can be tested on outputting this content into models (with the constraint off):

```
In [11]: all = Response.objects.all()

In [12]: all[0].short_url_slug
Out[12]: u'o'

In [13]: all[4].short_url_slug
Out[13]: u'o'

In [14]: all[4].short_url_slug == all[0].short_url_slug
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: Please show the following additional details: Output of the query `SELECT version(), current_setting('standard_conforming_strings') AS scs;`, and your Python, Django and psycopg2 (or whatever DB adapter you're using) versions. It would also be very helpful to turn `log_statement = 'all'` on in `postgresql.conf`, reload PostgreSQL, and examine the logs to identify the text of the suspect `INSERT` as PostgreSQL sees it.

Comment: U+00A4 (CURRENCY SIGN) is a completely different character from U+00D4 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX), for which `o` is absolutely a valid slugification.

Comment: Do you have `unidecode` installed? What about `pytils`?

Comment: Interesting ... but I'm getting a unique constraint violation on the column when I try to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django slugify doesn't support unicode, you should use [unicode-slugify](https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify)

(As read in two scoops of Django http://django.2scoops.org/)

Comment: Interesting - but I'm using AutoSlug and a custom slugifyer - shouldn't that go around Django's defaults?

Comment: What is your custom slugifyer? by default it's django's one it pyutils or unicode is not installed. 

It make's me think about the normalyze method pt the [unicodedata](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) module. But i wasn't abale to reproduce your results with the default 4 forms...

Comment: in the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/django-autoslug/settings.html) s is said that if unidecode or pyutils are not installed it use the defaut django engine. 

could you try with the "é" u'\xe9' and see if it's translated to e??

Comment: I actually ended up using another solution, so I am unable to test this :(, but I DEFINITELY missed this as part of the documentation, and was almost certainly the cause!